# Timed Autosave Plugin/Feature for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autosave

I'm looking for a way to have my files autosave in Eclipse on a timed interval, rather than when I build, because I'm quite stupid and forget to constantly (if ever) save my work. I lost about 6 hours of work this morning and I do not want that happening again, if possible.

Is there a plugin (or maybe an Eclipse feature) that will save my project files every x minutes? I know I need to develop habits to save my files on my own, but I get caught up in the code at times, so I hope you understand my dilemma.

I've seen a number of other posts about an autosave on build plugins / feature, but that is not what I'm looking for, even though google seems to think it is.

Comment: +1 i lost 15 minutes today. There must be an option in eclipse, but where...

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + S  is THE keybinding

Comment: @martini There definitely should still be an autosave feature. If I wanted to revert, I could always go back on git. Or, turn off the feature!

Comment: totally agree, I mentioned the key bind bc. thought it might be useful

Comment: @martini It definitely is. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is an issue since 2003 in eclipse... it's embarrassing. 26 users and nothing. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=34076